# Rails Bootstrap modal trying to update wrong model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

My Rails app has Tasks and a Task has_many Taskups (updates or comments).
While displaying a page that lists the Tasks, I want to have a Bootstrap modal list the existing Taskups and allow the addition of a new Taskup.

This is the code inside the Tasks list to launch the modal:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#task-<%= task.id %>" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" type="button">Comments</a>
<%= render :partial => "taskups/comments", locals: {task: task} %>
```

The modal pops-up and you can see a list of the Taskups for that Task.  There is also an input field for a new Taskup.

This is the modal code:

```
<div id="task-<%= task.id %>" class="modal" style="display: none;">
<%= simple_form_for :taskup, :url => {:action => :create} do |f| %>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&#215;</a>
    <h3>Comments</h3>
  </div>

  <div>
  <% task.taskups.each do |taskup| %>
      *
      <%= taskup.comments %>
      </br>
  <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= f.input :comments, :label => 'New Comment:'  %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :task_id, :value => task.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <%= f.submit "Save Comment", :class => "btn-primary" %>
    <a class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" href="#">Close</a>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

But, if you enter some text in the input box and click on the "Save Comment" button, the next screen you see is the Task input form.

It's like the code is trying add a new Task instead of a new Taskup.

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE1

This is the controller code for Taskups.  (But, I think the Task controller is getting called somehow)

```
# POST /taskups
# POST /taskups.json
def create
  @taskup = Taskup.new(params[:taskup])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @taskup.save
      if @taskup.taskstatus_id != nil
        Task.find(@taskup.task_id).update_attributes(:taskstatus_id => @taskup.taskstatus_id)
      end
      format.html { redirect_to @taskup, notice: 'Task Update was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @taskup, status: :created, location: @taskup }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @taskup.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

This is Taskups model:

```
class Taskup < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :taskstatus
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :user

  default_scope { where(tenant_id: Tenant.current_id) }

  default_scope :order => 'taskup_date ASC'
end
```

Comment: Please paste controller & model code.

Comment: I added the controller and model to my question.

Comment: Well, first of all, the form is calling the create action, not the update.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the question to show the create action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
<%= simple_form_for :taskup, :url => url_for(:action => 'create', :controller => 'taskups'), :method => 'post' do |f| %>
```